# Excel MsgBox with VBA for multiple linked range

Tags: excel, vba, range, msgbox

I need some help with an excel problem.

It is a combination of the two problems below:

1) [Excel - Popup message with sound alert when cell value meets certain criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267766/excel-popup-message-with-sound-alert-when-cell-value-meets-certain-criteria)

2) [VBA code to show Message Box popup if the formula in the target cell exceeds a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013285/vba-code-to-show-message-box-popup-if-the-formula-in-the-target-cell-exceeds-a-c)

In **Sheet1**, I have a range of products and sales figure.
Example: [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktiuv.png)

In **Sheet2**, I have multiple columns of sumif() functions. Example: [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSYAF.png).
It contains a column of names in (A:A) and data in (B:B) & (C:C) which are linked to cells in other sheets. I would like a pop up notification saying ("Text in column A" sold is > 20) when the value of any cell in column B exceeds 20 or column C exceeds 40.

**For example**: If one of the cell value in column "B" gets updated to 33 (which is >20) and the corresponding cell value in column "A" contains text as "Charlie", excel sheet should popup message saying "Charlie sold is > 20".

The below VBA code accomplishes this **IF** it was raw data. However, it does not work when the cells are linked to data from other sheets, as in the case of this workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.column = 2 and target.value > 1 Then
       MsgBox target.offset(0,-1).text & " sold is > 20"
   End If
End Sub
```

This alternative code works with data linked from other sheets, however it only applies to a specific cell, not an entire column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value > 20 Then
    MsgBox "B2 is >20", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

**What I'm trying to achieve is this**: As I input my raw data in Sheet1, the figures in Sheet2 column(B:B) and column(C:C) get updated. Once any of the cells in Sheet2 column(B:B) exceed 20 or column(C:C) exceed 40, there will be a popup notification that links back to column A text such as `MsgBox target.offset(0,-1).text & " sold is > 20"`. Is there a way to combine the above two codes to achieve this? 
Any alternative solutions are welcome too, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Compare all the Sums in Summary table

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim RangeToCheck As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set RangeToCheck = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B5") 'See comment #1

    For Each Cell In RangeToCheck.Cells
        With Cell
            If .Value2 > 20 Then
                MsgBox "Product: " & .Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Value2 & _
                " in cell: " & .Address & " is " & .Value2 & ">20", vbOKOnly
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

### Comments

1. I recommend turning the range on *Sheet2* to Excel table and using `ListObject` and `Listcolumns` instead.
2. Off topic hint: You can also use some counter, put the range into an VBA array and loop through array, it will be faster, than refering to sheet cell one after another. See [Writing efficient VBA UDFs (Part 1)](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt answer, this works great! I will try to implement your suggestions as well.